# Renaming Files on NTFS drive via File Explorer lead to Input/Output Error in Directory

Tags: mount, fstab, ntfs, read-only

Working on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on hardware that was a mid-tier gaming PC when custom built about 12 years ago. 2 hard drives, primary was reformatted with 4 partitions: swap, boot, OS, and data, secondary drive was left untouched as NTFS with data from when machine was a Windows PC. Was always a secondary NTFS data drive, never had an OS installed.

At first, I manually mounted the NTFS drive as needed, and moved around files between various folders. But I decided to auto mount this drive in `fstab` using settings:

```
/dev/sdb1   /media/location  ntfs  defaults  0  0
```

Which worked fine, no errors when i checked, automatically mounted when I rebooted (for some reason verification came back with an error when I tried using the UUID, so just using `/dev/sdb1` until I can figure that out). All seemed fine, able to access the drive immediately upon boot, able to access and play media files without issue.

I had a subfolder of the drive open in the File Explorer window, and was renaming files. Select the file, hit <kbd>F2</kbd>, edit name, and hit enter to save the new name. Never had any warnings or errors appear at this point. Did this for 50-60 files. However, I then navigate out of this subfolder, and then back to it, and on return I receive an Input/Output error, stating it cannot retrieve the file information of one of the files with a changed name. The file explorer window does not show any files or data in this subfolder.

In terminal, I navigate to this directory, and ls displays all the files, both the ones still with the original names, and the ones with edited names, as well as an error for each file that was renamed.

In searching about this issue, I see information that states using `ntfs` instead of `ntfs-3g` in `fstab` means that the drive is read-only. If this is the case, why was I able to rename the files? And if I was able to rename the files via the file explorer, why did it then lead to an Input/Output error?

Everything else on the drive in other directories is still accessible, and I was able to use the terminal to move everything that has its original name to a new directory on the data partition of the other. I have confirmed that I can access and use these moved files.

I installed `nfts-3g` and tried to run `ntfsfix` on the drive, but it says:

```
refusing to operate on read-write mounted device
```

Any idea why changing file names caused such an issue? Any way to correct the errors? Or do I need to look into transferring all data to other drives and reformatting this drive?

Comment: Have you actually checked the drive health?  ie. SMART etc.  IO errors can be a result of actual physical errors & you've provided no details of you actually checking this (*did you explore system logs as to what the IO error was; if there are multiple lines of messages on screen you only see the last line unless reading logs, but first line usually contains the key detail*).  You can successfully read-write to other areas of the disk & won't experience problems until you attempt to use the *problematic* part of the dis; your logic in the question seems to ignore this.

Comment: I don't know how to check drive health, or what SMART is. I haven't worked in a Linux environment for nearly a decade. Even back then my knowledge was limited and rudimentary. I decided to install Ubuntu just a couple weeks ago, and still barely know anything. Ubuntu is supposed to be one of the easier, better supported, off-the-shelf type of distros, and I only deviated from the basic installation instructions to format the primary drive that had Windows on it. I fundamentally don't understand why I, if I had permission to do so, changing file names would cause physical errors in the disk.

Comment: @SamB it is an NTFS partition. You check those using WINDOWS.  And the reason: Linux does not like dirty filesystems from other systems and to prevent dataloss will error out. The problem is with the journaling so that is about files, dirs and the nodes for them.

Comment: I only learned to edit the fstab because i searched how to automount a drive. I only learned about ntfs-3g while trying to solve this error on my own, searching this and other forums. I feel like the machine in the Chinese Room at the moment, taking what i see on my computer, and searching online, and then taking what I find online and applying it on the computer, but no real comprehension of what most of it means.

Comment: Do I need to have the drive connected directly to a Windows machine, or can I have it mounted on the Ubuntu machine, and check it via a remote connection of some type?

Comment: SMART is the *self monitoring analysis & reporting tool* built into disk drives made over last ~30+ years (including SSDs). They allow you to check health of the drive components (*without using actual disk; only data from chips on the drive itself*) and OS doesn't matter (ie. same for GNU/Linux, windows, OSX or BSD as hardware feature). You use software on the PC to read it and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools maybe helpful; GUI or command line tool can be used; I always use *live* media so drive isn't being used, and check health whenever I get strange behavior, esp. IO issue.